# Help on creating test users on iTunes Connect Portal

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

[image]

Dear all,

Actaully i am a admin user.i am trying to create a test user account for in app purchases...
when i log into the iOS Provisioning portal, i cant able to create test users.
also refer the screenshot i attched.in that it is mentioned that "Manage Your In App Purchases" module on the iTunes connect home page.but i dont find that kind of a module over there.it is given that "Manage your in app purchases" module will be shown if

> 1) you are an admin or Technical user
>   2) and your team agent has clicked
>   through the latest iOS developer
>   program License Agreement in the iOS
>   Developer provisioning portal.

can you please tell me why the "Manage your in app purchases" module is not shown to me?

And in the second point , i cant understand what they mean it actually ( related to team agent)

Please help me out , i have been searching a lot for this for the past 3 days...

Thank you for all your help and time.

Comment: Have you created any In-App purchases? Maybe it isn't showing up because there are none to manage. I think the same happened to me.

Comment: thanks for the reply..ok if the In-App purchase is not showing up due to that i didnt created any menas ok...but why cant i create test users as mentioned...when i create new user i dont find anything to select between user types like TEST USERS

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill all financial and banking information before those options appear.